# How to check whether a string is present in a string array in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7

I know that the Windows Phone runtime is small which don't have many classes and methods .But I was not able to find any direct method to check whether an element is present in an array
.ie there is no Exits or Contains method in the string[].

I know if I put a loop things will work. But wanted to confirm whether there is any direct way.

Answer (score 4):

Use Linq (extension) method.

```
string[] ar = { "A", "B", "C" };

if(ar.Contains("A"))
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks AVD.We are using this now. Any idea whether this is better than loop in terms of performance as this is running in mobile?

Comment: @Joymon   - The Contains method perform linear search so you may either use loop or this method. You may use Array.BinarySearch() if an array is sorted.